# Adding application to complete action using list in Motorola Xoom

Tags: android

I try to add my application into "complete action using" for call contact action. I added the following intent filter to the manifest as described in docs and other answers

```
  <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
```

and it works ok for samsung s2 and s3 but does not work in Motorola Xoom device. My application does not appear on the list. Can anyone give me a hint how to fix or work it around?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fix or workaround, as the XOOM is not a phone and therefore has no ability to place phone calls, so there is no list for you to appear on.

Comment: Skype found a way to add itself to the list, so there is a way to do so.